# How to partition a hard drive that has no OS installed?

Tags: hard-drive, windows-8, partitioning

I have a 500 GB hard drive. The laptop came with Windows 7 preinstalled.

Now as I am installing Windows 8, **I have deleted the C drive**. So I have 460 GB free unused space where I can install Windows 8.

But the Windows 8 installer **does not give me any option** to partition the 460 GB.
The only option available are "**Refresh**" and "**Load driver**" or just selecting the 460 GB HDD and installing Windows 8 in it.

**So how can I partition this 460 GB before I install Windows 8 in it?**

**Edit**: Can you suggest me some tools that partition the hard drive and **RUN independently** (as I do not have any OS installed) from a USB ?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

As you may know, this task is fairly easy to do after the install of the OS is done. All you have to do is resize your primary 460 and create an unallocated free space and then convert that into a partition. All can be done by the **in-built partition manager of Windows 8**.

However, This can also be achieved by using **[G-Parted Live CD](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/livecd.php)**.

Comment: GParted is highly recommended.

Comment: Holy crap guys :D. Love you all. I just made more points in this question than I made in 10 questions lol

Comment: Many of us love OS, so my guess is the Gparted Recommendation alone got you at least 6!

Answer (score 15):

You need to click 'Drive Options (Advanced)', which will give the rest of the options including 'New'. Select the unused space, 'New', and the size (it will default to the full amount).

Comment: Thanks.But as I had mistakenly "deleted" the C drive, that option is not avaliable with me.I think G parted is the way.

Comment: GParted is a great tool and I generally can't recommend it highly enough, but I'm certain you could have achieved the same thing via the windows install CD which you already had. I don't see why it would not have presented the usual advanced options

Comment: Perhaps you already have 4 primary partitions there? When you deleted the C drive, you're only left with creating one more partition.

Comment: @MartheenCahyaPaulo You mean 3 primary partitions. If the OP had deleted a partition yet was unable to create another primary it would indicate the partition deleted was a logical partition within an extended volume.

Answer (score 0):

frst U install window 8 in that 460 gb free space. 
Aftr installing window successfully .
Right click on computer u see  3rd optn "manage" select it nd open it.
aftr opning it u see "diskmngmnt" optn open it 
then u see ur 460 gb space as "c drive " 
NOw right click on it nd then selct optn "shrinl vlume"
After it u selct spce in "MB" as u want 
.theck click next ...next nd at last "finish"

ur new drive made successfully....